# Can another tread unlock a mutex although it has not acquired the lock previously?

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex

Can thread `t2` unlock a mutex `m`, although the mutex was previously locked by thread `t1`? Can the mutex `m` be unlocked twice?

To illustrate these questions, I wrote the following little script:

```cpp
#include <atomic>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

class spinlock_mutex {
    std::atomic_flag flag;

   public:
    spinlock_mutex() : flag(ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT){};
    void lock() {
        while (flag.test_and_set(std::memory_order_acquire)) {
            std::cout << "cloud not acquire lock" << std::endl;
        }
        std::cout << "acquired lock" << std::endl;
    }
    void unlock() {
        flag.clear(std::memory_order_release);
        std::cout << "release lock" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    spinlock_mutex mutex{};
    std::lock_guard<spinlock_mutex> lock_a(mutex);
    std::thread t2([&](){mutex.unlock();});
    t2.join();
    std::cout << "t2 has unlocked the mutex" << std::endl;
}
```

Execution of this code prints the following:

```sh
acquired lock
release lock
t2 has unlocked the mutex
release lock
```

It seems to me that the main thread acquired the mutex via the `lock_guard` facility. Then, thread `t2` unlocks the mutex. At the end of the main scope, the destructor of `lock_guard` unlocks the lock (shouldn't that been unlocked by now?) again. (When I replace the custom `spinlock_mutex` with `std::mutex` the program runs without any complaints but of course does not print any information).

So I wonder if thread `t2` can indeed unlock a mutex it has not locked, and which mutex does the main thread unlock at the end? [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex/unlock) warns of undefined behavior in the description of the `unlock` function, and I wonder if the program documents this?

Comment: _"..warns of undefined behavior in the description of the unlock function, and I wonder if the program documents this?..."_ all you can so with Undefined Behaviour is to fix the program to remove it.

Comment: "Well, he thinks he's got control of that resource, but I'm going to use it anyway and not tell him that I did anything to it." Recipe for disaster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link you shared already has the answer

> The mutex must be locked by the current thread of execution, otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

"Undefined behavior" in C++ doesn't mean "the program can define it". It literally means "this behavior will never be defined by any conforming compiler". See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior) for more details on the terminology.

Specifically, the standard (§32.5.4.2.1) has this to say

> The expression `m.unlock()` is well-formed and has the following semantics:
>
> Preconditions: The calling thread owns the mutex.

And §16.3.2.4 defines a function's preconditions as

> Preconditions: the conditions that the function assumes to hold whenever it is called; violation of any preconditions results in undefined behavior.

So unlocking a mutex you don't own in undefined behavior. It could work, it could throw an exception, it could ignore the call, it could [summon demons out your nose](http://catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html).

Comment: "Undefined behavior" doesn't mean "will never be defined by a conforming compiler". It means that the language definition doesn't tell you what the code does. Implementations are free to define that behavior and to document what they do.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not allowed.

[std::mutex::unlock](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex/unlock)

> The mutex must be locked by the current thread of execution, otherwise, the behavior is undefined.